# Why does Vim show these strange characters sometimes?

Tags: arch-linux, vim, character-encoding, text, text-formatting

Why is Vim showing these strange characters?

[image]

I'm  running Arch, and `locale -a` gives this:

```
C
en_US.utf8
POSIX
➜$>
```

I've also tried

```
:set fileencoding=utf-8
```

But, that didn't help either.

Comment: Does `:set list!` fix the problem?

Comment: yep...I found a mistake in my vimrc, which adds this:  `" so invisibles
set list
set listchars=
"set listchars+=tab:\ 
set listchars+=trail:·
set listchars+=extends:»
set listchars+=precedes:«
set listchars+=nbsp:⣿
  
`  This is causing the problem, but removing the +=tab causes all tabs to be replaced with a `^I`

Comment: You can keep `listchars`, it's quite useful occasionally.  Just don't set `list` in your `vimrc`.  Use `:set list!` to toggle it when you need it.

Comment: Thanks...I'll do that...I also changed the tabs to something a little less intrusive (two whitespaces).  This is good enough for me and working with C files.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @"Sato Katsura", here is what I did:

The characters were caused by my overlooking something in my .vimrc.  That character is called

```
" so invisibles
"set list
set listchars=
"set listchars+=tab:\ 
set listchars+=tab:\ \ 
set listchars+=trail:·
set listchars+=extends:»
set listchars+=precedes:«
set listchars+=nbsp:⣿
```

I commented out `set list` because I don't really need it all the time...I also changed the `tab` substitution to two whitespaces, since anything else was unbelievably annoying.